# Is there a way to detect when a swagger changes?

Tags: swagger

My coworker, after 2 months of not turning anything in, has been placed under me.

Today they changed some api calls to make something of mine that had been running for months stop working. They changed the name of some fields and how they work.

How can I detect when they do this in the future.

Swagger.io is the swagger i'm talking about.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is old, but for the sake of people ending up here looking for an answer these days: now there is a solution, called Swagger Diff. It can compare two `swagger.json` files, and highlight any changes.

- Ruby version: https://github.com/civisanalytics/swagger-diff
- Java version: https://github.com/Sayi/swagger-diff

The Ruby version you can even use in the build process, and fail the build if there's any incompatibility. The Java version currently only shows a list of changes.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there's no tool to provide diffs between swagger docs, though such a tool [has been requested](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/issues/233). It won't necessarily be easy to create such a tool since if an operation path is changed, for example, there's no real way of linking between the old and the new.

However, Swagger does not replace proper API version management. Just like any piece of software, APIs need to be controlled. You have the `apiVersion` property which should be used to indicate such changes.

Answer (score 2):

Ron's right in the larger scheme of things, but if you just need to show that a breaking change occurred, remember that swagger produces a standardized JSON file that you can diff and track in version control. If you have version control on your API code *and* your swagger output, you can show when someone does something they shouldn't, because the code and the swagger will not be together in the same diff.

In other words, if you track both code and swagger JSON, you can enforce the requirement that both should appear in the same commit diffs, and that the api version be updated according to some standard.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but wanted to give others the opportunity to finally find the tool they need.

I was in the same situation for a project a while ago and needed something usable for failing builds when breaking changes are encountered after a commit so I needed to write my own tool.

It's called Swagger Brake (yeah I was in a funny mood) and here you can find some info how it's used: [Introducing Swagger Brake](https://arnoldgalovics.com/swagger-brake-api-compatibility-checker/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=swagger-brake-api-compatibility-checker)

Here's the GitHub repo: https://github.com/redskap/swagger-brake

Here's the relevant documentation: https://redskap.github.io/swagger-brake/

Also, the tool seamlessly integrates with Maven/Gradle for the Java ecosystem in the format of plugins but if you're trying to use it for a different setup, you can use the CLI.